# Create and maintain several ssh sessions in Python

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

Once my program has been launched, it opens any number of ssh sessions (user defined) and runs specific commands on the servers indefinitely (while true loop) or until the user quits. For efficiency reasons I want to create each session only once, then be able to run the commands until the user quits.

How can I do this in python? I ran across a cool method in another post which used `subprocess` to run a command and capture its STDOUT. How can I first initiate the session, then run looped commands?

Any links to process-like stuff in Python would also be appreciated. This is my first python application.

Comment: I think this has been done before, I don't remember the name, but it is an open source project (python too) that lets you manage multiple remote machines through SSH all at the same time.

Comment: Sounds cool. My application would really benefit from that (although coding it myself would be a great learning process), although it would need some extra functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Ignoring Python for the moment, you can multiplex `ssh` sessions by adding this

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath /tmp/ssh_mux_%h_%p_%r
ControlPersist 1h
```

to your `~/.ssh/config` file. After connecting to a machine once, the ssh session to this machine will stay open, and subsequent commands will execute on this machine near-instantaneously thereafter. You could then use Python subprocess to call ssh and execute commands on that machine as-needed, and the session will be reused without having to do anything special.

You could also call `ssh` with the `-F` flag pointing to an alternate config file, if you'd rather not make the session multiplexing the default behavior (or you're deploying for other users who might not have it as their default).

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll google around for ssh caching and let you know if this is the route I want to take. Thanks

Comment: You'd have more luck googling "multiplexing," if memory serves. There are a few [caveats](http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2010/02/ssh-controlmaster-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly/) that are worth knowing too.

Comment: So this does look pretty cool, however it seems to fail when lots of data is being sent through the socket. Seeing as the commands run are user-specified, I can't be sure it won't fail. I think I'm going to have find another way of doing this. Thanks for this awesome tidbit though.

Answer (score 4):

OPTION 1: 
You can re-use a ssh process by redirecting input using a PIPE.

Here is a basic example:

```
[(Z) </tmp> ]% touch input_file
[(Z) </tmp> ]% tailf input_file | ssh <remote_host>
```

Now try writing something into the file

```
[(Z) </tmp> ]% echo "date" >> /tmp/input_file
```

Here is a way to make use of this in Python using subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
SSH_CMD = "cat -| /usr/bin/ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -T -x %s "
HOSTNAME = "127.0.0.1"
s = subprocess.Popen(SSH_CMD%HOSTNAME , shell=True, close_fds=True, 
stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This starts a subprocess which can be re-used. Please note that `close_fds=True` is required because of a known bug (http://bugs.python.org/issue2320).

```
>>> REMOTE_CMD = "date"
>>> s.stdin.write( REMOTE_CMD +
... "\necho 'remote command completed with exit code = '$?\n")
>>> s.stdout.readline()
'Thu Feb 16 20:01:36 PST 2012\n'
>>> s.stdout.readline()
'remote command completed with exit code = 0\n'
```

`echo 'remote command completed with exit code = '$?\n` line is used to know that the remote command finished and it is done writing to s.stdout. This is also useful to know the exit code of the remote command.

To use the same subprocess for executing another remote command:

```
>>> REMOTE_CMD = "uptime"
>>> s.stdin.write( REMOTE_CMD +
... "\necho 'remote command completed with exit code = '$?\n")
>>> s.stdout.readline()
' 20:02:17 up 28 days,  9:15, 48 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.02, 0.05\n'
>>> s.stdout.readline()
'remote command completed with exit code = 0\n'
```

Coming back to your question, once you create a ssh subprocess, you can keep sending the remote commands. Once the user is quits, you can kill the subprocess.

```
>>> s.kill()
```

OPTION 2: I have never used this, but ssh has a ControlMaster option for re-using ssh. Check man page for ssh_config(5)

Comment: I'll investigate this as a solution, looks nifty. Thanks for your help, I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: hi, using your solution, if I give ls as the remote command, I will not know for how long the pipe will have data. I wish to stop at some point, and then send in the next command..

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To know when to stop doing readline(), you'l have to compare each output line with "remote command completed with exit code = XX" (Note the echo command added after REMOTE_CMD in my original code snippet). It helps me to know the exit_code of the REMOTE_CMD too.. but I agree, this has its disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pexpect module. It allows opening and maintaining ssh sessions, which you can reuse to send in multiple commands. You can send in any commands and expect particular outputs based on which you can perform other logical operations.

Answer (score -1):

Tried mixing it up with multithreading?