# Persistent ssh session in Python using Popen

Tags: python, ssh

I am creating a movie controller (Pause/Stop...) using python where I ssh into a remote computer, and issue commands into a named pipe like so

```
echo -n q > ~/pipes/pipename
```

I know this works if I ssh via the terminal and do it myself, so there is no problem with the setup of the named pipe redirection. My problem is that setting up an ssh session takes time (1-3 seconds), whereas I want the pause command to be instantaneous. Therefore, I thought of setting up a persistent pipe like so:

```
controller = subprocess.Popen ( "ssh -T -x <hostname>", shell = True, close_fds = True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
```

Then issue commands to it like so

```
controller.stdin.write ( 'echo -n q > ~/pipes/pipename' )
```

I think the problem is that `ssh` is interactive so it expects a carriage return. This is where my problems begin, as nearly everyone who has asked this question has been told to use an existing module:

- [Vivek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10684894/654789)
- [Chakib's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15776329/654789)
- [shx2's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772823/654789)
- [Crafty Thumber's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15167643/654789)
- [Artyom's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14996859/654789)
- [Jon W's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1233808/654789)

Which is fine, but I am so close. I just need to know how to include the carriage return, otherwise, I have to go learn all these other modules, which mind you is not trivial (for example, right now I can't figure out how pexpect uses either my `/etc/hosts` file or my ssh keyless authentications).

Comment: I'm assuming it doesn't work by just adding '\n' to your string?

Comment: @kyle no I tried `\n` and `\r`

Comment: On top of needing to add `\n`, you often also need to `stdin.flush()`.

Comment: @abarnert before, during or after =P

Comment: @puk: Each time you want to make sure the other side of the pipe has seen everything you've written, you want to `flush`. You can do it after each and every write, if you want. Doing it _before_ the write won't help much. And I believe that doing it _during_ the write is impossible, because pipe writes (up the platform's max size) are guaranteed atomic.

Comment: By the way, as far as other modules go—forget using `pexpect` or `Fabric` or whatever to make it slightly easier (but still horribly painful) to automate the `ssh` tool; use something like `paramiko` instead of the `ssh` tool in the first place. All of these problems, instead of just getting a little easier to solve, just don't exist in the first place.

Comment: [Why don't you use `ControlMaster` option to avoid 1-3 seconds delay?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9322548/4279)

Comment: @abarnert: `fabric` is higher level than `paramiko` and I believe it is `fabric`'s maintainer that keeps `paramiko` alive. For such a simple task, any solution will do.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: OK, yeah, using Fabric as an SSH library makes sense. The key point is to use an SSH library (as you say, any SSH library will make this trivial), rather than using a command-line library to drive the `ssh` tool.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I actually say that, but I thought `ControlMaster` was just so idle ssh connections wouldn't close. I will give it a try

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian am I supposed to ssh in a particular way? With `ControlMaster` if I ssh too many times, I get this error `mux_client_request_session: session request failed: Session open refused by peer`, `ControlSocket /tmp/ssh_mux_... already exists, disabling multiplexing`

Comment: @puk: It probably means that the first connection (the one that establishes tcp connection for itself and all consecutive corresponding  ssh commands) failed in such a way that left stale `ControlPath` file and you have to remove it manually. Keep the very first connection alive and clean up after it if dies unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a newline to the command, you will need to add a newline to the string:

```
controller.stdin.write('\n')
```

You may also need to flush the pipe:

```
controller.stdin.flush()
```

And of course the controller has to be ready to receive new data, or you could block forever trying to send it data. (And if the reason it's not ready is that it's blocking forever waiting for you to read from its stdout, which is possible on some platforms, you're deadlocked unrecoverably.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it's not working the way you have it set up, but I'll take a stab at this. I think what I would do is change the `Popen` call to:

```
controller = subprocess.Popen("ssh -T -x <hostname> \"sh -c 'cat > ~/pipes/pipename'\"", ...
```

And then simply `controller.stdin.write('q')`.